# Not able to send messages to RabbitMQ using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jms, rabbitmq, spring-jms

I am trying to send a message to `RabbitMQ` installed on my `localhost` using `Spring 4` but for some reason the message is not getting sent and I do not get any error either. It looks to me that my Spring config  (`beans.xml`) is not correct.

Please guide.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- RabbitMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.5.xsd">

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.study.jms.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World (Spring-RabbitMQ)!" />
    </bean>

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest" port="5672"/>
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
    <rabbit:queue name="helloQueue"/>

</beans>
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        HelloWorld helloWorld = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

        //send message
        System.out.println("Sending message....");
        AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
        template.convertAndSend(helloWorld.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you have any logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell RabbitMQ how to route the message.

Since you are not creating an exchange or binding the queue to an exchange, you can route to the default exchange (`""`) using the queue name.

You either need to set the `routingKey` property (`routing-key` attribute) on the template to the queue name, or you need to include it in your `convertAndSend` call:

```
template.convertAndSend("", "helloQueue", helloWorld.getMessage());
```

RabbitMQ simply drops messages that are successfully delivered to an exchange but not routed to any queue.

See the [RabbitMQ Tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) to understand exchanges, routing keys etc.

The [Spring AMQP samples repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples) has Spring Boot versions of the tutorials.